# foreach loop corrupting my array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

### Explanation

I have a multidimensional array that is iterated over to created a categorized view of people with different research interests. The main array look something like this:

```
Array
(
    ...
    ['Cell Biology']      => Array(4 elements)
    ['Molecular']         => Array(6 elements)
    ['Biology Education'] => Array(14 elements)
    ['Plant Biology']     => Array(19 elements)  <--- Last element in array
)
```

I know that the entire array is intact and correctly structured. The only information that is inside these array is an user id, like so:

```
Array ('Plant Biology') 19 elements
(
    [0] => 737
    [1] => 742
    [2] => 748
    ...
)
```

My problem is that after i run the main array through a foreach loop the last 'sub-array' gets messed up. By messed up I mean that what you see about instead look like:

```
String (13 characters) 'Plant Biology'
```

This is without doing at all anything inside the loop with to the array that gets corrupted.

Any tips to what it might be?

### PHP Code

```
  // ---> Array is OK here
  echo "<h2>Research divided</h2>";
  // Loop areas and list them in 2 columns
  foreach($research['areas'] as $area => $areaArray) {
      // ---> Here it is already corrupted
      $count = count($areaArray);
      if($count > 0) {
          echo "<h3>$area</h3><hr/>";
          echo "<ul>";
          // Loop users within areas, divided up in 2 columns
          for($i=0 ; $i<$count ; $i++) {
              $uid = $areaArray[$i];
              echo "<li>$uid</li>";
          }
          echo "</ul>";
      }
  }
```

Comment: It seems that maybe something in the array before it is messing it up. Going to try a `for`-loop instead of `foreach`-loop

Comment: Are $area or $areaArray being used in different function elsewhere in your script? Wht happens if you rename them to $loop_area and $loop_areaArray?

Comment: Could you provide code that can actually reproduce your problem? Like the necessary to create the `$research['areas']` array.

Comment: Sidenote: You wanna use a `td` element instead of a `li` element inside the `tr` tag. :)

Comment: i think it could be on the $research['area'];, you probably mean $research. unless $research has an array() with the name of area then you aint got an array to loop at... why not try is_array() to check if the array is an array then loop else display an error code.

Comment: Can you give more information about the data structures and variables you're using, as we dont really have enough information to see exactly what you can and cant do.

Comment: @Pekka: That solved it, thanks! Please write it as an answer so that I can give you a mark and make it more evident for people who read this later.
@Philiipe: I did use <td> but took them away to make the code easier to read for you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are $area or $areaArray being used in different function elsewhere in your script? Wht happens if you rename them to $loop_area and $loop_areaArray to prevent accidental overwriting of variables?

Comment: That solved it thanks. It has to do with me actually using the `$area` variable in a foreach loop earlier. In that loop it was passed by reference: `&$area`. When the looping again without passing it as reference it messes up the last array element. This is very dangerous behavior since sometime variable like `$_SESSION` are looped with foreach and who knows if some extension library or other authors code has a foreach loop with `&$_SESSION` in it. The link below provided by Jai is where it is explained.

Comment: After being bitten by this multiple times, I promised never to use foreach loops. However, the solution is to make sure you always unset the variables created after the loop. That's not very convenient, so I just don't use foreach.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an error that can occur if you loop over the array previously by referance using the same variable name for the value.

So if earlier in your code $areaArray is used in a foreach by referance it might corrupt your data.

Make sure both variables in your foreach are not used previously or unset them before the loop.

Check out:

http://bugs.php.net/29992

For more info on this kind of problem.

Comment: That is the exact bug! THanks for the helpful link